# How can I write (userInput >= "50") properly?

Tags: c#

I mean to say "If the number typed by the user is greater than 50 then..."
How can I write this properly? Because this error shows up in Visual Studio:

Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        string message = (userInput >= "50") ? "Your number is greater than 50" : "You number is less than 50";

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: take the `userInput` and parse it into an `int`, then you can compare it directly like `(userInputAsInteger >= 50) ? ...`

Comment: I was going to post it as an answer, but @BradleyDotNET and others beat me to it.. see below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings are not numbers, so parse it:

```
int userInputNum = 0;
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputNum))
{
    string message = (userInputNum > 50) ? "Your number is greater than 50" : "You number is less than 50";
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
else
{
    //Junk user input
}
```

Note that you can use `int.Parse` instead, but it will throw if the user inputs a non-number. The `out` keyword in the second argument forces the called function to populate the argument before returning (used because the signature of TryParse calls for it). Also, your logic was greater than *or equal to* 50. The code above is strictly greater than.

Your original code doesn't work because you are comparing the user input to a string (hence the *"cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and **'string'**"*) because you have compared it to `"50"`. A string cannot be "greater than" or "less than" another string, only "equal to" (`==`) or "not equal to" (`!=`).

More specifically, the `>` operator is not defined on `string` and so cannot be used to compare two of them.

Comment: Can you please simply explain what this expression means? if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputNum))

Comment: And what does this mean? int userInputNum = 0;

Comment: errr.. A variable declaration? You have to declare the variable before you can pass it as an `out` parameter...

Comment: No, I mean from where did Num come from? And why = 0?

Comment: I added "Num" to indicate that its a number (and to distinguish it from the `userInput` variable the string is stored in). 0 was just a convenient initializer. `TryParse` will overwrite it anyways.

Comment: So you put 0 because you have to put something, right?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't leave uninitialized variables lying around (and C# will error if you try to use one).

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```
 var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and (userInput >= "50") to

```
(userInput >= 50)
```

just remove qoutations

Comment: Really? This is effectively the same as AndersonRici's answer, and has the exact same flaws. The primary difference here is that you store the result of the parse instead of using it directly in the conditional

Answer (score 0):

You've stored the value in a string variable. Thus, you should convert it to int so you are able to compare.

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    string message = (Convert.ToInt32(userInput) >= 50) ? "Your number is greater than 50" : "You number is less than 50";

    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Same problem as before, `Convert.ToInt32` uses `Parse`, so this throws with bad user input

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't understand, what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @TheGameChanger It will crash (unhandled `FormatException`) if the user input is "abcd" or any other non-numeric string. Don't take my word for it though! Try it, and learn a bit about exceptions :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ah, yes indeed.

Comment: You can use `Convert.ToInt32`, you just need to use an `if` (or something similar) to check whether or not the string is in a valid input to Parse.

Comment: @Ben At which point you've parsed the string into an int.... so why do it again? Also, there is no built-in function to do this to my knowledge

Comment: I am new to C# programming, what do you mean @Ben?

Comment: @TheGameChanger It's possibly a bit overkill for such a simple comparison, but as Bradley pointed out, if the user types in 'abcd', it will throw an exception. What you can do instead is check if the user input *can* be converted to an int, then compare it. But again, Bradley has also stated there are other functions that handle this already.